# get the values in the popup window for corresponding row in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

```
<table>
    <tbody align="center" style="font-family:inherit">
        <?php
        $resultbooked ="SELECT *,b1.paid_amount as sub_total FROM booking_details b1,payment_history b2 WHERE b1.id='".$bookingid."' AND b2.booking_id='".$bookingid."'";
        $exe= mysql_query($resultbooked);
        $i=0;
        while($bookedrow= mysql_fetch_array($exe))
        {
        $i++;?>
        <tr>
            <td style="display:none;"><?php echo $bookedrow['id']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $i;?></td>
            <td>
                <?php $date_format=$bookedrow['present_date'];
                echo $chng_date=date('d-m-Y',strtotime($date_format));?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php echo $bookedrow['paid_amount'];
                $total=$bookedrow['sub_total'];?>
            </td>
            <td>
              <p class="current_pay" booking_id="<?php echo $bookingid;?>">
                <p class="current_pay" pay_id="<?php echo $bookedrow['id'];?>"><span class="icon-print" style="cursor:pointer;"></span></p>
                <?php
                }?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<div id="payment_details<?php echo $bookedrow['id']; ?>" class="show_current_payment" style="display:none;margin: 0 auto; width: 60%; background:#FC9;">
    <button onclick="printbill()" class="no-print button sButton bOlive">Print</button>
</div>
```

i'm trying to get the value **$bookedrow['id']** from the **select** query to the div **id**-**payment_details** but i can't get the **$bookedrow['id']** value? how can i get that value in that id value!!!

Comment: put your that div in the while loop

Comment: i want to display the whole payment history,from that i can select one payment,that will display in popup....when i put that div in while loop,i getting the single record of payment,not the whole payment in the DB

Comment: @ SKRocks ji have you understood my question?kindly make me to fix that problem

Answer (score 0):

If the $bookedrow["id"] is always the first one in the table as it seems this would work. It gets the text inside the first td element in the page (so use this after php loop when the text is echoed there) and adds the value to the hidden input value.

```
 $("#id-payment_details").val($("td:first").text());
```

Comment: what does it mean?can you please explain it

Comment: Sorry I was about to write more but forgot about it. See my updated answer and ask if you need any further explanation. :)